# CMakeLists.txt "-Wl,--whole-archive" options causes SIGABRT error on Samsung Galaxy Note2, S3 (Kitkat 4.4.2)

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

If add `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive` options to CMakeLists.txt.
`System.loadLibrary("~");` always causes SIGABRT error.
Error: `A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000036ae (code=-6), thread 13998`

I found that these crashes raise on Galaxy note 2, Galaxy s3 (Exynos 4 Quad 4412, ARM Cortex-A9 CPU, Android 4.4.2 Kitkat)

Creating new project using Android Studio project "Native C++" template and add one line code below on `CmakeLists.txt`.

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive")
```

It always crashes at `System.loadLibrary("~");` line.

Code repository based on "Native C++" template: https://github.com/kujyp/AndroidNativeWholeArchiveCrash

NDK Version: 14.1.3816874

```sh
cat ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/source.properties
> Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
> Pkg.Revision = 14.1.3816874
```

<strike>If changing ndk version to 20(20.1.5948944), an another error comes up.

Error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libc++_shared.so" needed by "libnative-lib.so"; caused by library "libc++_shared.so" not found`</strike>
Resolved(but still crashes on galaxy note 2): https://github.com/kujyp/AndroidNativeWholeArchiveCrash/commit/479c15918241e5c68621f27b22c1d56c6c9906ce


Any clues for the reason? Or solution?

Background:
https://gist.github.com/kujyp/9c4c8c63cfd12f797639874d151b1707#file-with_tf1-4_cmakelists-txt

My project has tensorflow-core.a(v1.4.0) as dependency. So without `--allow-multiple-definition` or `--whole-archive`, tensorflow library raises some build errors. So my compiler options, linker options are just same as in tensorflow repository.
options: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.4.0/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake/CMakeLists.txt#L45-L48
an issue about `--whole-archive` option: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4242

With tensorflow library, gcc should be used, not the clang as a build tool. From ndk 15, gcc was deprecated.
(From tf1.13.1, clang was used as a build tool, but my project is using tensorflow 1.4.0 or 1.5.1 or 1.12.0)
Ndk version for tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.4.0/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/Dockerfile.android#L44

Comment: Why do you use `--allow-multiple-definition` in the first place?

Comment: Or `--whole-archive`? That's not something that you can just add to your linker flags at any place. That needs to be used on individual libraries.

Comment: "If changing ndk version to 20(20.1.5948944), an another error comes up." Are you building with an ancient version of the gradle plugin?

Comment: @DanAlbert
Thanks for your mention "That needs to be used on individual libraries."
I will try it.

Comment: @AlexCohn I just added background description.

Answer (score 0):

`-Wl,--whole-archive` should not be added to linker flags without causion. Even native codes did nothing, `-Wl,--whole-archive` flag caused the crashes on specific (ancient) devices.

Attaching `-Wl,--whole-archive` to an invididual library and `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` to other libraries resolve this crash.

Resolved CMakeLists.txt: https://gist.github.com/kujyp/9c4c8c63cfd12f797639874d151b1707#file-resolved_tf1-4_cmakelists-txt-L35-L37

Thanks to @DanAlbert